# Java-Constants-like Map object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecma

I am trying to get a static Java-like map object working in Javascript. I am not a javascript expert, but am wondering if this is possible. What I am trying to do is the following:

I am defining

```
const MY_CONST_1 = 'Constant 1 value';
const MY_CONST_2 = 'Constant 2 value';
```

and a "map-like" object like this:

```
const CONST_AMOUNT_MAP = {
  MY_CONST_1: 30,
  MY_CONST_2: 22
}
```

Then, in a function I define:

```
function getAmount(constValue) {
   return CONST_AMOUNT_MAP[constValue];
}
```

My expectation would be that the above function when called with

```
getAmount('Constant 1 value')
```

returned the number "30". However,

```
CONST_AMOUNT_MAP[constValue];
```

returns "undefined". Only

```
CONST_AMOUNT_MAP[MY_CONST_1]
```

returns the correct amount.

Is it possible to define an Object such as CONST_AMOUNT_MAP that allows to lookup entries based on pre-defined const variables rather than based on the actual value of the consts?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do, but I think you want `const CONST_AMOUNT_MAP = { [MY_CONST_1]: 30, [MY_CONST_2]: 22 }` -- that is, evaluate the property names by putting `[]` around them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define an object literal, the key names are given literally - they're not evaluated. In other words:

```
const CONST_AMOUNT_MAP = {
    MY_CONST_1: 30,
    MY_CONST_2: 22
}
```

...makes an object with a key named `MY_CONST_1`, not the *value* of any variable you've defined with the name `MY_CONST_1`.

You can achieve what you're after by instead declaring your keys wrapped in `[]`, which will force the enclosed to be evaluated.

```
const CONST_AMOUNT_MAP = {
    [MY_CONST_1]: 30,
    [MY_CONST_2]: 22
}
```

Or

```
const CONST_AMOUNT_MAP = {};
CONST_AMOUNT_MAP[MY_CONST_1] = 30;
CONST_AMOUNT_MAP[MY_CONST_2] = 22;
```

Note that the keys, however you add them, must be strings or symbols. Since you mention 'map', be aware that [there are true maps in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), in which the keys can be of any data type.